# CKEditor plugin: Hightlight selected text by hovering on a new item in the toolbar and selecting from a drop down

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I'm new to the CKEditor and I'm trying to create a simple plugin. What I'm hoping to accomplish is to allow the user to highlight some text and then hover on a new item in the toolbar that drops down on mouse over a few different highlight color options for the text. For example, the user could highlight some text, hover on my new item and then select a highlight color. This will be similar to the 'BGColor' plugin except instead of opening a color palette to choose from, the user would select from a drop down of options similar to when you choose to change the font size you have a list of options such as '10', '11', '12', etc.

Any help would be appreciated on how to pull this off. I was hoping to check out how 'BGColor' and 'FontSize' plugins where implemented, but I can't find these in ../ckeditor/_source/plugins. Am I looking in the right spot? Also, the link for plugins here - http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide isn't clickable so I'm not sure if there's a place for plugin documentation that I can check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development of plugins has not been documented as of yet that's why you can't get to the documentation. You can look at fontsize iand BGColor in ckeditor->_source->plugins that should get you started. let us know when you get stuck be happy to help some

Comment: Any idea on when the documentation will be available?

My plugin is taking shape.  I have it working by using richcombo that will highlight selected text a different color based on what you choose from the combo box.

Is it possible to add individual style to each option in the combo box?  This would be similar to how the Styles combo box works where each option for Blue Title, Red Title, etc. looks different.

Comment: I have no idea I'm don't work for them or anything I just read somewhere on there site about it that's how i knew the hadn't been documented.

I have really only developed a very simple plugin nothing as fancy as what your planning /working on.. its sounds cool though.  

if the styles combo box can do it what you want then I'm sure it can be done though I have no clue how to do this off hand

sorry I can't be more helpful